# Kendo Core - basic assistance needed

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I am trying to use Kendo's free source code.  I simply want to display the data-title inside a tabstrip, but so far am unable to.  The core code comes with one dataviz and it does not work for me.  How can I display the data-title inside a tabstrip?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Kendo sources -->
    <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <!--<link href="kendo/styles/kendo.dataviz.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

    <script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo/js/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Source -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/stylesheet.css" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="view" id="home" data-title="Home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <div data-role="tabstrip">
                <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="tabstrip">
                <a data-role="button" href="#menupage">Menu</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there are lots of javascript files in the js directory, but I don't need to include them individually right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your div data-role="tabstrip" to data-role="navbar"

```
<div data-role="view" id="home" data-title="Home">
  <div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <span data-role="view-title"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <a data-role="button" href="#menupage">Menu</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fixed sample at http://jsbin.com/suhaso/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes, I suppose that works, thank you.  But how would I get the tabstrip to work?  It looks much nicer.  I am used to using the professional version at work

Comment: nevermind!  I uncommented the two sources above and it works perfectly now!  not sure why